# Label for checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox

```
<div><label for="group">Select lists</label></div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group1" value="1" title="Main List" />
<label for="group1">Main List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group2" value="2" title="Secondary List" />
<label for="group2">Secondary List</label>
<label for="group1 group1">Check All</label>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to target the label with the `for=...` attribute or do I need to assign an `id`?

Comment: What _exactly_ isn't working for you?

Comment: What do you mean by targeting the label? Labels refer to controls (fields), not vice versa.

Comment: The label dont check both boxes.

Comment: Yes you can. just include each input fields inside of respective label tags. Ex: `<label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Click here to check this</label>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `<label>` labels a *single* form control. If you want to provide a "label" for a group of form controls, use a fieldset with a legend.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Select lists </legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group1" value="1"><label for="group1">Main List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group2" value="2"><label for="group2">Secondary List</label>
</fieldset>
```

If you want to provide "check all" functionality, then you need to use JavaScript.

For example:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Select lists </legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group1" value="1"><label for="group1">Main List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group2" value="2"><label for="group2">Secondary List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="all" value="all"><label for="all">Check all</label>
</fieldset>
```

and

```
function checkAll() {
    var boxes = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
}

document.querySelector('[value="all"]').addEventListener('change', checkAll);
```

(Compatibility with older browsers that don't support `querySelector` is left as an exercise to the reader)